# A good error measure for matrices of different sizes needed

Tags: matrices, mean-square-error

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{I\times J}$ be the so-called reference matrix, which will be estimated by an algorithm. The estimate will be called $A'\in \mathbb{C}^{I'\times J'}$, and might have other dimensions than $A$. For the case that the dimensions of $A$ have been correctly estimated (i.e $I' = I$ and $J' = J$), the error $e$ shall be computed by $e=\frac{||A'-A||_2}{||A||_2}$.

What would be a nice extension to this way of error-measurement for the case that $A$ and $A'$ do not have the same size?

Thanks in advance for your input! :)

Comment: pad with zeros and use the same norm?

Comment: Yes, this is already something that I was thinking of. I just wanted to know if this is something where more "sophisticated" methods  exist. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Peak of cross correlation? It really depends on your application.